# using a variable within a php class

Tags: php, wordpress, class

I searched and read about private, public & protected within a class, and I maybe just don't know how to phrase what I'm trying to do.

I am not able to get a class function to use a variable defined as public.

Here's my class:

```
class Store {

  private $wpdb;
  public $store;

  public $payroll_total_dollars;
  public $payroll_regular_dollars;
  public $payroll_overtime_dollars;
  public $payroll_vacation_dollars;
  public $payroll_salary_dollars;
  public $payroll_commission_dollars;
  public $payroll_total_percent;
  public $the_last_query;

  public function __construct() {
    global $wpdb;
    $this->wpdb = &$wpdb;
    $this->setup_payroll();
  }

  public function set_store($store) {
    $this->store = $store;
  }

  function setup_payroll() {
      if($this->store != 'all_stores') {
          $this->payroll_regular_dollars = $this->wpdb->get_var( $this->wpdb->prepare ("SELECT sum(regular_hourly) FROM adt_sales WHERE store= '%d'", $this->store));
          $this->the_last_query = $this->wpdb->last_query;
      }
  }
}

$store01 = new Store;
$store01->set_store('1');
```

I'm trying a few things to get the query working in the `setup_payroll()` function.

If I do this: `echo $store01->store`, it returns `string(1) "1"`

If I do this: `echo $store01->the_last_query`, it returns `string(58) "SELECT sum(regular_hourly) FROM adt_sales WHERE store= '0'"`

So clearly since the query is receiving `0` where it should actually be `1`, the result is `NULL`.

If I hard-code the number `1` into the query in the `setup_payroll()` function, it works as expected and returns the value I am looking for within the `$payroll_regular_dollars` variable, so I don't know where I'm going wrong in trying to get `$this->store` into that query!

Please help save my sanity!

Comment: The query is executed _before_ you set the store, thats why.

Comment: Like @tkausl said, your query is getting called upfront in the constructor before you set the store.  Setting the store after instantiating isn't changing the result of the query because it ran already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create $store01, the code in your constructor is called. You can't execute code before the constructor; if you want to invoke set_store you need to do it in the constructor so that setup_payroll has that number to reference. (or alternatively you could just invoke setup_payroll() outside of your constructor).

You could change your constructor like so:

```
public function __construct($v) {
    global $wpdb;
    $this->set_store($v);
    $this->wpdb = &$wpdb;
    $this->setup_payroll();
}
```

Then just instantiate it with

```
$store01 = new Store(1);
```

This will set_store to whatever you pass into the constructor when a new object is instantiated. With this, setup_payroll should behave a bit more like you expect.

Comment: Perfect thank you!  This is my first Go at OOP, and so far it is amazing to write all of these lines just once!!